StreamPlot3d for the magnetic field of a loop
I am trying to go beyond StreamPlot in the case of a current loop that produces a magnetic field. My code works for StreamPlot, but does not end when I use the same field expressions with StreamPlot3D. Code is as follows:
Clear["Global`*"]
$Assumptions={_Symbol \[Element]Reals};
radius=1;
element[theta_]:={radius Cos[theta],radius Sin[theta],0};
fieldPoint={x,y,z};
fpToElement=fieldPoint-element[theta];
modR2=fpToElement.fpToElement;
modR=Sqrt[modR2] //ExpandAll //FullSimplify;
unitVector=fpToElement/modR // FullSimplify;
tangent=D[element[theta],theta];

{dBx[x_,y_,z_,theta_],dBy[x_,y_,z_,theta_],dBz[x_,y_,z_,theta_]}=tangent\[Cross]unitVector/modR2//FullSimplify;

{Bx[x_,y_,z_],By[x_,y_,z_],Bz[x_,y_,z_]}:={
NIntegrate[dBx[x,y,z,theta],{theta,0,2\[Pi]}],
NIntegrate[dBy[x,y,z,theta],{theta,0,2\[Pi]}],
NIntegrate[dBz[x,y,z,theta],{theta,0,2\[Pi]}]
};

Print["\nSTREAMPLOT"]
(* This works in a few seconds*)
StreamPlot[{Bx[x,0,z],Bz[x,0,z]},{x,-1,1},{z,-1,1},ImageSize->Large, StreamPoints->Coarse]//AbsoluteTiming
(* This does not end *)
(*
StreamPlot3D[{Bx[x,y,z],By[x,y,z],Bz[x,y,z]},{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},{z,-1,1},StreamPoints->Coarse]
*)

The results of StreamPlot are as expected:

However, if I comment out the StreamPlot[] code and uncomment the StreamPlot3D[] part (at the bottom), I get no results for hours beyond three indications that the third field component

has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the
region with boundaries...

Any help will be much appreciated.

If you prevent the definition of Bx, By, Bz to be evaluated for symbolic argument and and introduce "Thread" in their definition you can get a reasonable time for evaluation. Further note, that the plot is symmetrical in x,y,z around  the origin. Therefore it is good enough to restrict the plot region to: {x,y,z} element {0,1}. With this:
Thread[{Bx[x_, y_, z_] /; NumericQ[x], By[x_, y_, z_] /; NumericQ[x], 
    Bz[x_, y_, z_] /; NumericQ[x]} := {NIntegrate[
     dBx[x, y, z, theta], {theta, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
    NIntegrate[dBy[x, y, z, theta], {theta, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
    NIntegrate[dBz[x, y, z, theta], {theta, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]}];

StreamPlot3D[{Bx[x, y, z], By[x, y, z], Bz[x, y, z]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 
   0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, StreamPoints -> Coarse]


I get 3 minutes for evaluation.
